# Time to read/write memory on the DUE

Tags: arduino-due, time, sram

I am onto a project where a need more memory. I saw the 23LC1024 chips are very popular with the Arduino DUE.

A very helpful person told me he did some timing tests on the 23LC1024 and a page read/write of 32 bytes costs about 100 μs.

I am interested in real time audio manipulation application (using the Arduino Due's ADCs and DACs).

This time of 100μs per 32 bytes seems a lot for the application, though i am not sure.

Are there benchmarking tests of the Arduino DUE for the time it takes to read/write to its memory, so i can compare with this chip and decide what to do?

Comment: You really don't want to use an external SPI memory for that.  Switch instead to either a processor with more on-chip RAM (maybe another SAM series part, or maybe the top end Teensy), or even more appropriately for such a task, switch to an SoC which uses a variety of external *parallel* DRAM and likely has on-chip caches to further speed access to it.  These don't necessarily cost any more today, though they do add some system complexity.

Comment: Personally I use the PIC32MZ with an external I2S DAC or CODEC chip. 200MHz 512kB RAM, 2MB flash... And programmable in the Arduino IDE...

Comment: Besides, using DMA to read from the ADC and write to the DAC leaves plenty of CPU time for shuffling memory around between internal and external RAM blocks.

Comment: I didn't know this chip was programmable from the arduino IDE! Does it follows the same code structure (setup, loop)? Also the chip is available in bulk form. I would have to build a circuit and solder components to program it right? Any references on the circuit?

Comment: Also, could you please mention the I2C DAC chip you were using?